# How can I save videos from iCloud Drive or Google Drive to photos on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, video, instagram, files.app

in the past I’ve been able to click a video in iCloud drive, and the option to ‘save to camera roll’ has been there. From there, I can use the instagram app and it will find the video stored in my photos/videos on the phone.

Now this option isn’t there. I can’t find a way to save the mp4 files to my phone at all. It’s not a huge file (35MB) but sending it to myself by email hasn’t worked.

Clicking 'open with instagram’ on the video in iCloud Drive does nothing, the menu goes away but it doesn’t open. If I click ‘open with winzip’ it will open in that app and allow me to play, but again gives me no option to save.

I managed this two weeks ago several times and it let me save it. What can I do???

Answer (score 2):

I use this method for Google Drive, I think it's OK for iCloud Drive. Touch the three vertical dots and there will be the "**Send a copy**" option; Now, as you will see, there will be "**Save Video**", it will start exporting and your video will be saved in the roll

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used this option (it works with google drive but not iCloud drive) and it brings up a pop-up saying ‘preparing to export.’ This lasts a minute or so then goes away. When I check, the file is not in my camera roll, in photos or videos. ...

Comment: I find strange, sure you have enough space for the video? 
In iCloud drive, after selecting the photo/video, in the lower left there is the export option, and there is "Save video/image".

Answer (score 0):

On iCloud Drive, find the video you want to save, long press on it, press share then save video then it should be in the photos app. It worked for me so I hope this helps you